# BioC packages in a text

Tags: pdftex

how is it possible to have the following font for a Bioconductor library (for example "limma") in a text?

Best

e

[image: Example]

Comment: It seems `\texttt{limma}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
the \texttt{limma} Bioconductor package
\end{document}
```

> [image]